# Spotify API: Playing a specific part of a song

Tags: position, spotify, spotify-app

I'm trying to play a song from a position other than the beginning of the track.

I've found that `player.position` = X will work as a standalone function, such as triggered by a button, but triggering it on `player.observe(models.EVENT.CHANGE...` results in a crash.

I figure this is because the track hasn't actually started playing once the event occurs as the `player.position` may still be at the previous song's position.

I've also experimented with `sp.trackPlayer.seek()` which seems to give the same results.

So has anyone got a song to start playing at another position than 0? (Or made the playhead jump ahead after the event of playing a new song?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the position after the uri, for example:

var uri= 'spotify:track:xxxxxx#02:04'

player.playTrackFromUri(uri)

See this sourcecode if you want inspiration:

https://github.com/Iteam1337/Wejay/blob/master/javascript/room.js